# Questions tab on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow

I have observed that when I go to [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) and click next, I see the same subset of questions that were on the last page.

Is it due to the fact that continuous ranking or ordering keeps changing after every fixed interval `delta`?

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you look at the newest questions, because they are sorted most recent first. New questions are added to the first page all the time, so by the time you get to the end of a page and click to the next, the new questions have pushed the questions at the end of every page to the next page.

Comment: Ok thanx Richard Close